# Show Salesforce tests results in VSTS build result

Tags: unit-testing, salesforce, azure-devops

I set up a build in VSTS to run ANT migration tool to deploy to Salesforce Org. I would like to somehow publish the results of the unit tests to the VSTS, so I can leverage the [VSTS test results overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/test/review-continuous-test-results-after-build?view=vsts). I can see the test results in the log output of the ANT task in the build job, but using the VSTS overview seems more convenient. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the test results file, then you can use the [Test: Publish Test Results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=vsts) task to publish the results to VSTS.

Besides, you can check if this article helps: [Versioning and Deploying Salesforce Metadata using TFS/VSTS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/najib/2016/06/16/versioning-and-deploying-salesforce-metadata-using-tfsvsts/)

Comment: The article helped me set up the build jobs, but it doesn't concern with the tests publishing. I don't know how to get the tests results file from Salesforce.